# HTML Link text not rendering well

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, materialize

I'm having an issue with a text in my HTML side navigation.

It looks like something is super imposing on the text. Anyone experienced this before?

[image]

Side Nav HTML Code

```html
<li class="no-padding">
  <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
    <li>
      <a class="collapsible-header">Funding<i class="material-icons">credit_card</i><i class="nav-drop-icon material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></a>
      <div class="collapsible-body">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Recurrent ","FundAccount ",new { Area="Customer "})#!">Fund Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Recurrent ","FundAccount ",new { Area="Customer "})#active_plan_section">Active Recurrent Payment Plans</a></li>
          <li><a href="@Url.Action(" IdleCash ", "MyPortfolios ", new { Area="customer "})">Cash Accounts</a></li>
          <li><a href="@Url.Action(" RequestWithdrawal ", "MyRequests ", new { Area="customer "})">Request Withdrawal</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: and what text is there "superimposing" over / under other menu item? Can you copy and paste to text file? Can you inspect in the console? The above code is not suffiicient to determine root cause but looks like a css positioning issue perhaps

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS to it in a [mcve]

Comment: Did you try to set `<a>` display `block`

Comment: The problem is that your "plans" from upper list item does not fit in your container and is pushed on the next line behind "Cash".

Comment: Thanks @Marmellad
I've fixed it now.